# I need to divide a large file into chunks.since my file size is greater(50GB) i need to split into larger chunks

Tags: c++, buffer, fstream, chunks

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 11788889

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream infile("hello.txt");
unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
int read_file_position=infile.tellg();
cout<<"input file position"<<read_file_position<<endl;
while(infile.read((char *)buffer,BUFFER_SIZE))
{
read_file_position=infile.tellg();
cout<<"input file position"<<read_file_position<<endl;

}
}
```

what i tried splits my file only into chunks of bytes..splitting into MB or GB would be great..if there is a way to divide it into bigger chunks it would be helpful..also since my records do not have a fixed length so the chunk size would vary.

Comment: You need to split it into chunks why? and do you mean in memory, or splitting it into separate smaller files on the disk?

Comment: cause I need to further provide those specific chucks to separate threads..

Comment: but that is a latter part..first splitting into chunks is main

Answer (score 0):

yes but since I have a larger file I don't want write it to another file and waste time...

I have records like this..

```
ID:1002:: TP://reports/timing_report1.txt::TPS:counter/ffa::TPE: counter/ffd:: PGR: CLK::PTY:max::SL:-0.48::LAY:M2:: SEL::SLLT:1.0:: PTY:ANY::LAY:M1&M2:: PRG:ANY:: CELL:ANY:: REG:ANY
ID:1003:: TP://reports/timing_report1.txt::TPS:counter/ffb::TPE: counter/ffc:: PGR:CLK:: PTY:max::SL:-0.3::LAY:M1:: SEL::SLLT:1.0:: PTY:ANY::LAY: M1&M2:: PRG:ANY:: CELL:ANY:: REG:ANY
```

now if I want to divide in chunks..i don't want a chunk to contain half the record..so I want a chunk to have the full record..that if I divide in 2 halfves then I don't want a record to b split into half.so I need to search for the next occurrence of ID and add the previous half in the previous chunk n from the next ID in that chunk

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read data by chunks and than pass chunks to several threads do the following

```
void *pManyChunks = malloc( NUM_THREADS * sizeof(YourRecord) );

while( not end of file )
{
  read sizeof(YourRecord)*NUM_THREADS bytes to pManuChunks

  pass (YourRecord*)((char*)pManuChunks + sizeof(YourThread)*0) pointer and sizeof(YourRecord) to first thread
  pass (YourRecord*)((char*)pManuChunks + sizeof(YourThread)*1) and sizeof(YourRecord) to second thread
  pass (YourRecord*)((char*)pManuChunks + sizeof(YourThread)*2) and sizeof(YourRecord) to third thread
  etc
}
```

Comment: my record size is not fixed..it varies...n same is with the file size.that is y I used # define for a buffer size n file size so that I can change it any given point of time..i want to divide my file in chunks for efficient reading...the threading will happen once the records are split properly.dt is nt the major concern now..only splitting into proper chunks is.